# Custom Visualforce Page for Shared Activities

Tags: visualforce, tasks, shared-activities

I'm trying to create an inline Visualforce page to substitute for the standard 'Name' related list on Shared Activities. The problem I am trying to solve is getting more information that just the related name and type (Lead or Contact) to display in the name related list on the task detail page.

I created a basic page using the code below, but it seems as though Task.WhoId only looks at the Primary Contact and not other related contacts.

Has anyone used TaskWhoIds to return a list of ALL related contacts/leads for shared activities ? And am I am to use TaskWhoIds to get the accountIds of other related contacts ?

Thanks!

```
  <apex:page standardController="Task" >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Related Contacts">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Task.Whoid}" var="Whoid">
        <apex:column value="{!Task.whoid}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!Task.Accountid}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
```